# Is it possible to enable TrafficStats on android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, traffic-measurement

I'm trying to get the total number transmitted bytes from the device (using [getMobileTxBytes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#getMobileTxBytes%28%29).

The number i'm getting from the method call in the emulator is -1 (which means that this method not supported on the device).
Is there any way to make the emulator return a reasonable number here? the best would be a number that will increase as i'm browsing the web in the emulator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the look at the stock Android source code 
(/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_net_TrafficStats.cpp), this class is pretty dumb, it has the network device names hard-coded inside, and it is looking at "rmnet0" and "ppp0" only, as mobile device names. So it is not going to detect network traffic in the emulator, unfortunately.